# Fotorama Fullscreen has a problem when leaving fullscreen mode in Magento2

Tags: magento2, fotorama-slider

On a lot of mobiles or ipads, I had tried to click open the fullscreen and then exit fullscreen. The page will dead every time. Should I check the fotorama version ….? Or any solution for this problem?

Here is the demo video => 
https://youtu.be/krxrjMBuK1A

Comment: I found that when click image and be fullscreen mode on mobile. The  <div class="page-wrapper" style="display: none;"> will be "display: none", only on mobile or pad devices. And when exit fullscreen, the "display: none" will not disappear. Why this action different from PC device?

Answer (score 2):

I had remove the code $pageWrapper.hide(); in gallery.js

```js
if (this.isTouchEnabled) {
    this.settings.$element.on('tap', '.fotorama__stage__frame', function () {
        var translate = getTranslate($(this).parents('.fotorama__stage__shaft'));
        if (translate[1] === '0' && !$(this).hasClass('fotorama-video-container')) {
            self.openFullScreen();
            //self.settings.$pageWrapper.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

For temporary solve the problem happened on the mobile device.
This is my solution detail:
http://goo.gl/DfHzOk

Comment: Your link is not work anymore, could you update?